# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED (reported when built with MSVC but not when built with GCC)

Tags: c, heap-corruption

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *string;
    int end;
    size_t length;
} str;

str* new_string(size_t len)
{
    str *ptr;

    ptr = (str*) malloc(sizeof(str));

    ptr->string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    ptr->length = len;

    ptr->string[len] = '\0';
    ptr->end = 0;

    return ptr;
}



void resize_string(str *ptr, size_t new_size)
{
    ptr->string = (char *)realloc(ptr->string, sizeof(char) * new_size);

    if (ptr->end == ptr->length) {
        ptr->string[ptr->length] = ' ';
        ptr->string[new_size] = '\0';
    }
    ptr->length = new_size;
}

void append_string(str *ptr, char ch)
{
    if (ptr->end == ptr->length) {
        size_t new_length = ptr->length + 5;
        resize_string(ptr, new_length);
    }

    ptr->string[ptr->end] = ch;
    ptr->end++;
    ptr->string[ptr->end] = '\0';
}

char *raw_string(str *ptr)
{
    return ptr->string;
}

void delete_string(str *ptr)
{
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->string != NULL) {
            free(ptr->string);  //deugger here is showing the break statement and HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED. 
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
}

int main() {
         char ch;
         str *string = new_string(5);
         while (1) {

             ch = getchar();

             if(ch=='\n'){

                 break;
             }

             append_string(string, ch);
          }

         printf("%s",raw_string(string));
         delete_string(string);

         return 0;
 }
```

The above code runs fine in ubuntu , without any seg. fault,but in visual studio 2013 the code blows at runtime. Debugger is showing break statement when i try to `free(ptr->string)` and HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED ,but i don't understand why?

Comment: `ptr->string[len] = '\0';` out of bounds.

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry! i have edited'

Comment: @Rouftantical Thanks for the edit. I had to reverse google the term `HEAD CORRUPTION` and it took me to some NSFW sites. :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean?Please explain.

Comment: @Rouftantical `type a[3];` .. `a[0]`,`a[1]`,`a[2]`. `a` has 3 elements, `a[3]`(4th element) : index `3` is out of range(0..2).

Comment: `a = malloc(type_size * len);` : `a` has len elements. a[len] is (len + 1) th element.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't think that this causes any problem because i am not accessing the array out of bound.

Comment: @Rouftantical Look at the my previous comment thought again. You have been access to the array beyond the number of apparently secure element.

Comment: @user3121023 tried it but it stuck again ;(

Comment: @user3121023 i have tried it also `ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*len + 1)` but still it is not working.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i don't know , how its working well in ubuntu?

Comment: @Rouftantical It can have been extra secured in alignment, or was a gap, just not immediately revealed, etc.. also You need to be rewritten as a whole not just one place.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for your help now its working because i have also changed the size in realloc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68915/discussion-between-rouftantical-and-bluepixy).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should enable checked allocs in your gcc-based environment, you will see you're corrupting the heap regardless of underlying library.

That said, you're reallocating with 1 less than expected, e.g. indexing 'new_size' (to set your NUL byte after) is out of range.